# Why xmlhttprequest response is in html code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

For some reason when I am sending an http request using xmlhttp the answer that I'm getting is in a html form

```
function HttpRequest(method, url, username, password) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let received_data;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responsejson);
            if (xhr.responseText == "access granted")
                console.log("ok");
            else
                console.log("error");
        }
    }
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send('username=' + username + '&password=' + password);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log("connected to " + url);
    }
 }

function send_data() {
    let method = 'POST';
    let url = 'https://localhost:83/android_app/server.php'; //url of the php 
server(must be https:// (secure) in order to make the connection using cordova app)
    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    HttpRequest(method, url, username, password)
   }
```

also the php server that I am sending this request it just that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($name=="admin" && $password=="1234"){
    echo "access granted";
}
else{
    echo "access denit";
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the response that I am getting

[image]

Comment: In your PHP file you have `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`. Why _wouldn't_ you get that HTML after requesting that page?

Comment: You mean that html your sending back?

Comment: `server.php` is like a subroutine. It does not need to be a html page if all you want to return to the Javascript is a simple string. Loose all the html

Comment: Everything you output on the server will be a part of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a function called via AJAX as if it were a subroutine. It should only  return what the caller wants. Currently with all that HTML in there that is being sent back to the AJAX call as well as the  `access granted` and therefore making what you want difficult to find.

So if you change the `server.php` code to

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($name=="admin" && $password=="1234"){
    echo "access granted";
}else{
    echo "access denit";
}
```

The all you will get returned to the AJAX call is either `access granted` or `access denit`, which is what you are testing for in the javascript